# How to handle Timeout exceptions during Offset Commit in a Kafka Streams application

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

If there is a timeout exception during committing offsets in a Kafka Streams application, does the ProductionExceptionHandler come into play?

```
Timeout of 60000ms expired before successfully committing offsets
```

I'm using a Spring cloud stream based Kafka streams application and I do have a ProductionExceptionHandler implementation configured to LogAndContinue. But it seems like the control doesn't come to the exception handler for this timeout exception and all stream threads die anyway.

What's the correct way to handle this? Here is the full error.

```
[-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.AssignedStreamsTasks         : stream-thread [stream-app-0d77ace1-4d20-413b-a71a-94cca3e620e0-StreamThread-1] Failed to commit stream task 0_3 due to the following error:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before successfully committing offsets {example-topic-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=139191, leaderEpoch=null, metadata='AQAAAXU0ut1W'}}
2020-10-17 04:05:23.410 ERROR [ratelimit-transformer,,,] 19 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [stream-app-0d77ace1-4d20-413b-a71a-94cca3e620e0-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following unexpected Kafka exception during processing, this usually indicate Streams internal errors:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before successfully committing offsets {example-topic-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=139191, leaderEpoch=null, metadata='AQAAAXU0ut1W'}}
2020-10-17 04:05:24.149 ERROR [ratelimit-transformer,,,] 19 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [stream-app-0d77ace1-4d20-413b-a71a-94cca3e620e0] All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.
Exception in thread "stream-app-0d77ace1-4d20-413b-a71a-94cca3e620e0-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before successfully committing offsets {example-topic-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=139191, leaderEpoch=null, metadata='AQAAAXU0ut1W'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `TimeoutException` is not very well managed by Kafka Streams and will eventually cause your StreamThread to crash. Most of a the time a timeouts happen due to network issue or kafka unavailability.

The error message logged by Kafka Streams is explicit  *"All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed."*; So, you can stop and restart your KafkaStreams application but if it's a network issue restartingyour app will not help.

Note that there is some works in progress :

- [Gracefully handle timeout exceptions on Kafka Streams | KAFKA-9274](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9274)
- [KIP-572 Improve timeouts and retries in Kafka+Streams](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-572%3A+Improve+timeouts+and+retries+in+Kafka+Streams)

You can configure an `java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` on your KafkaStreams instance to handle that exception ([KafkaStreams JavaDoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/latest/index.html))

Comment: While searching I did reach the KIP. I understand that the timeout error is expected if there is a network issue. I wanted to know if there is a way the streams app can handle blips and occasional errors by retrying with a backoff so that things start working once the connection issue is resolved. I guess I have to look for ways to add hooks to shut down the application when such an error happens. I wonder if the "retries" config mentioned here will work -- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html

Comment: There is no way to handle this other than configuring my app to restart. With the help of spring's actuator integration with kafka streams, i was able to get the DOWN status of a kafka streams service and have my deployment module take care of restarting a DOWN application after certain number of retries. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_health_indicator

Comment: The `retries` config does not apply to committing offsets, however, the consumer would retry internally anyway if a request times out. You can increase `default.api.timeout.ms` as mentioned in the `KafkaConsumer#commitSync` JavaDocs.